# WebAPI and ODataController return 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

Before adding OData to my project, my routes where set up like this:

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiById",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" },
            handler: sessionHandler
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" },
            constraints: null,
            handler: sessionHandler
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByIdAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" },
            handler: sessionHandler
```

All controllers provide Get, Put (action name is Create), Patch (action name is Update) and Delete. As an example, the client uses these various standard url's for the CustomerType requests:

```
string getUrl =  "api/CustomerType/{0}";
string findUrl = "api/CustomerType/Find?param={0}";
string createUrl = "api/CustomerType/Create";
string updateUrl = "api/CustomerType/Update";
string deleteUrl = "api/CustomerType/{0}/Delete";
```

Then I added an OData controller with the same action names as my other Api controllers. I also added a new route:

```
        ODataConfig odataConfig = new ODataConfig();

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: odataConfig.GetEdmModel()
        );
```

So far I changed nothing on the client side. When I send a request, I get a 406 Not Available error.

Are the routes getting mixed up? How can I solve this?

Comment: Add a prefix for your OData routes: routePrefix: "odata"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The order in which the routes are configured has an impact. In my case, I also have some standard MVC controllers and help pages. So in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
    {
        ODataConfig.Register(config); //this has to be before WebApi
        WebApiConfig.Register(config); 

    });
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

The filter and routeTable parts weren't there when I started my project and are **needed**.

`ODataConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //This has to be called before the following OData mapping, so also before WebApi mapping

    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.EntitySet<Site>("Sites");
    //Moar!

    config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "api", builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

`WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( //MapHTTPRoute for controllers inheriting ApiController
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And as a bonus, here's my `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute( //MapRoute for controllers inheriting from standard Controller
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

This has to be in that **EXACT ORDER**. I tried moving the calls around and ended up with either MVC, Api or Odata broken with 404 or 406 errors.

So I can call:

localhost:xxx/ -> leads to help pages (home controller, index page)

localhost:xxx/api/ -> leads to the OData $metadata

localhost:xxx/api/Sites -> leads to the Get method of my SitesController inheriting from ODataController

localhost:xxx/api/Test -> leads to the Get method of my TestController inheriting from ApiController.

Answer (score 80):

If you are using OData V4, replace `using System.Web.Http.OData;`

With `using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;` (**Please check the comments for the latest library**)

in the ODataController works for me.

Comment: This is the solution if you have a correct mapping.   

Why it is referencing Systme.Web.Http.OData by default?

Comment: using System.Web.OData.* namespaces are for odata v4 endpoints and System.Web.Http.Odata.* is all the older odata v1-3 stuff. I had this problem too, poorly documented too as examples on ms sites often mix the two up.

Comment: Now it's System.AspNet.OData

Comment: Now it's Microsoft.AspNet.OData

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/315: 
"With Microsoft.AspNet.OData v7.0, namespaces were changed from System.Web.OData to Microsoft.AspNet.OData."

Answer (score 11):

Set routePrefix to "api".

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<CustomerType>("CustomerType");

config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "ODataRoute", routePrefix: "api", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Which OData version are you using? Check for correct namespaces, for OData V4 use `System.Web.OData`, for V3 `System.Web.Http.OData`. Namespaces used in controllers have to be consistent with the ones used in WebApiConfig.

Comment: The distinction between the System.Web.OData and System.Web.Http.OData namespaces for versions 3 and 4 was causing me a lot of grief.  Note that this mistake resulted in a 406 Not Acceptable error in my case, as opposed to the 406 Not Available error that was reported by the OP.

Comment: I had a queryable 1st gen WebApi Controller (inhertied from ApiController).  Went to upgrade it to Web Api 2 & got invalid cast exceptions due to the select+expand bug. Once I re-wrote my controller [per sample #4 on this site](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24select%20and%20%24expand%20support&referringTitle=Specs) I started to get 406 Not Acceptable errors. I was able to quiet these by once again inheriting from ApiController in my new project rather than inheriting from OdataController. Furthermore, I have **no special odata route plumbling** in my project.

Comment: For me the hint with correct namespaces was correct. It seems that  scaffolding function is using the V3 namespace *System.Web.Http.OData* instead of *System.Web.OData*

Answer (score 10):

My issue was related to returning the entity model instead of the model I exposed (`builder.EntitySet<ProductModel>("Products");`). Solution was to map entity to resource model.

Answer (score 8):

Another thing to be taken into consideration is that the URL is case sensitive so:

`localhost:xxx/api/Sites -> OK` 
`localhost:xxx/api/sites -> HTTP 406`

Comment: Wouldn't that yield a 404?

Comment: This was also a cause for my OData calls not working, but didn't lead to a 406, but as Jerther rightly said, a 404. Still, worth remembering when making the API calls that casing is important.

Comment: That is very frustrating, but it ended up being my issue too - got 406 when the case was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The problem I had was that i had named my entityset "Products" and had a ProductController. Turns out the name of the entity set must match your controller name.

So

```
builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
```

with a controller named ProductController will give errors.

/api/Product will give a 406

/api/Products will give a 404

So using some of the new C# 6 features we can do this instead:

```
builder.EntitySet<Product>(nameof(ProductsController).Replace("Controller", string.Empty));
```

Comment: I didn't realize before that the "Products" should be the Controller prefix.. And also it's case senstive!

Answer (score 5):

None of the excellent solutions on this page worked for me.  By debugging, I could see that the route was getting picked up and the OData queries were running correctly.  However, they were getting mangled after the controller had exited, which suggested that it was the formatting that was generating what appears to be the OData catch-all error: 406 Not Acceptable.

I fixed this by adding a custom formatter based on the Json.NET library:

```
public class JsonDotNetFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public JsonDotNetFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override async Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await reader.ReadToEndAsync(), type);
        }
    }

    public override async Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        if (value == null) return;
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, new JsonSerializerSettings {ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore}));
        }
    }
```

Then in `WebApiConfig.cs`, I added the line `config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonDotNetFormatter())`.  Note that I am sticking closely to the order described in Jerther's answer.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ConfigureODataRoutes(config);
        ConfigureWebApiRoutes(config);
    }

    private static void ConfigureWebApiRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }

    private static void ConfigureODataRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonDotNetFormatter());
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<...>("<myendpoint>");
        ...
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem/solution in my case was even more stupid. I'd left test code in my action that returned a completely different model type, just a `Dictionary`, and not my proper EDM model type.

Though I protest that the use of HTTP `406 Not Acceptable` to communicate the error of my ways, is equally as stupid.

Comment: It can get even more stupid... I've spent a couple of days on this... `return Ok(result);` returns 406 if result is declared as `object` instead of `EntityType`...

Answer (score 3):

My error and fix was different from the answers above.

The specific issue I had was accessing a `mediaReadLink` endpoint in my ODataController in WebApi 2.2.

OData has a 'default stream' property in the spec which allows a returned entity to have an attachment. So the e.g. json object for `filter` etc describes the object, and then there is a media link embedded which can also be accessed. In my case it is a PDF version of the object being described.

There's a few curly issues here, the first comes from the config:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <!-- etc -->
</system.web>
```

At first I was trying to return a `FileStreamResult`, but i believe this isn't the default net45 runtime. so the pipeline can't format it as a response, and a 406 not acceptable ensues.

The fix here was to return a `HttpResponseMessage` and build the content manually:

```c#
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("myobjdownload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadMyObj(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var myObj = GetMyObj(id); // however you do this                
            if (null != myObj )
            {
                HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                byte[] bytes = GetMyObjBytes(id); // however you do this
                result.Content = new StreamContent(bytes); 

                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                result.Content.Headers.LastModified = DateTimeOffset.Now;  
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(DispositionTypeNames.Attachment)
                {
                    FileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", id),
                    Size = bytes.length,
                    CreationDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                    ModificationDate = DateTimeOffset.Now
                };

                 return  result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log, throw 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My last issue here was getting an unexpected 500 error after returning a valid result. After adding a general exception filter I found the error was `Queries can not be applied to a response content of type 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent'. The response content must be an ObjectContent.`. The fix here was to remove the `[EnableQuery]` attribute from the top of the controller declaration, and only apply it at the action level for the endpoints that were returning entity objects.

The `[System.Web.Http.Route("myobjdownload")]` attribute is how to embed and use media links in OData V4 using web api 2.2. I'll dump the full setup of this below for completeness.

Firstly, in my `Startup.cs`:

```c#
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyAPI.Startup))]
namespace MyAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // DI etc
            // ...
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ODataConfig.Register); // 1st
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); // 2nd      
            // ... filters, routes, bundles etc
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
        }
    }
}
```

`ODataConfig.cs`:

```c#
// your ns above
public static class ODataConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        var entity1 = builder.EntitySet<MyObj>("myobj");
        entity1.EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        // etc

        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

        // tell odata that this entity object has a stream attached
        var entityType1 = model.FindDeclaredType(typeof(MyObj).FullName);
        model.SetHasDefaultStream(entityType1 as IEdmEntityType, hasStream: true);
        // etc

        config.Formatters.InsertRange(
                                    0, 
                                    ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create(
                                                                    new MySerializerProvider(),
                                                                    new DefaultODataDeserializerProvider()
                                                                    )
                                    );

        config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();

        // note: this calls config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes internally
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "data", model);

        // in my case, i want a json-only api - ymmv
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

    }
}
```

`WebApiConfig.cs`:

```c#
// your ns above
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697934/catch-all-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api
        //config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());

        // ymmv
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // so web api controllers still work
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // this is the stream endpoint route for odata
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("myobjdownload", "data/myobj/{id}/content", new { controller = "MyObj", action = "DownloadMyObj" }, null);
        // etc MyObj2
    }
}
```

`MySerializerProvider.cs`:

```c#
public class MySerializerProvider: DefaultODataSerializerProvider
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ODataEdmTypeSerializer> _EntitySerializers;

    public SerializerProvider()
    {
        _EntitySerializers = new Dictionary<string, ODataEdmTypeSerializer>();
        _EntitySerializers[typeof(MyObj).FullName] = new MyObjEntitySerializer(this);
        //etc 
    }

    public override ODataEdmTypeSerializer GetEdmTypeSerializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType)
    {
        if (edmType.IsEntity())
        {
            string stripped_type = StripEdmTypeString(edmType.ToString());
            if (_EntitySerializers.ContainsKey(stripped_type))
            {
                return _EntitySerializers[stripped_type];
            }
        }            
        return base.GetEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);
    }

    private static string StripEdmTypeString(string t)
    {
        string result = t;
        try
        {
            result = t.Substring(t.IndexOf('[') + 1).Split(' ')[0];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

`MyObjEntitySerializer.cs`:

```c#
public class MyObjEntitySerializer : DefaultStreamAwareEntityTypeSerializer<MyObj>
{
    public MyObjEntitySerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider) : base(serializerProvider)
    {
    }

    public override Uri BuildLinkForStreamProperty(MyObj entity, EntityInstanceContext context)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(context.Request);
        string id = string.Format("?id={0}", entity.Id);
        var routeParams = new { id }; // add other params here
        return new Uri(url.Link("myobjdownload", routeParams), UriKind.Absolute);            
    }

    public override string ContentType
    {
        get { return "application/pdf"; }            
    }
}
```

`DefaultStreamAwareEntityTypeSerializer.cs`:

```c#
public abstract class DefaultStreamAwareEntityTypeSerializer<T> : ODataEntityTypeSerializer where T : class
{
    protected DefaultStreamAwareEntityTypeSerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        : base(serializerProvider)
    {
    }

    public override ODataEntry CreateEntry(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)
    {
        var entry = base.CreateEntry(selectExpandNode, entityInstanceContext);

        var instance = entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance as T;

        if (instance != null)
        {
            entry.MediaResource = new ODataStreamReferenceValue
            {
                ContentType = ContentType,
                ReadLink = BuildLinkForStreamProperty(instance, entityInstanceContext)
            };
        }
        return entry;
    }

    public virtual string ContentType
    {
        get { return "application/octet-stream"; }
    }

    public abstract Uri BuildLinkForStreamProperty(T entity, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext);
}
```

The end result is my json objects get these odata properties embedded:

```c#
odata.mediaContentType=application/pdf
odata.mediaReadLink=http://myhost/data/myobj/%3fid%3dmyid/content
```

And the following the decoded media link `http://myhost/data/myobj/?id=myid/content` fires the endpoint on your `MyObjController : ODataController`.

Answer (score 1):

Found in the GitHub error: "**Unable to use odata $select, $expand, and others by default #511"**, their solution is to put the following line BEFORE registering the route:

```
// enable query options for all properties
config.Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Source: https://github.com/OData/RESTier/issues/511

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to change a non-public property setter to public.

```
public string PersonHairColorText { get; internal set; }
```

Needed to be changed to:

```
public string PersonHairColorText { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (odata V3) I had to change name of OdataController to be same as provided in 
ODataConventionModelBuilder and that solved the issue

my controller:

```
public class RolesController : ODataController
{
    private AngularCRMDBEntities db = new AngularCRMDBEntities();

    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<tROLE> GetRoles()
    {
        return db.tROLEs;
    }
}
```

ODataConfig.cs:

```
public class ODataConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<WMRole>("RolesNormal"); 
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<WMCommon.DAL.EF.tROLE>("Roles").EntityType.HasKey(o => o.IDRole).HasMany(t => t.tROLE_AUTHORIZATION);
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<WMCommon.DAL.EF.tLOOKUP>("Lookups").EntityType.HasKey(o => o.IDLookup).HasMany(t => t.tROLE_AUTHORIZATION);
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<WMCommon.DAL.EF.tROLE_AUTHORIZATION>("RoleAuthorizations").EntityType.HasKey(o => o.IDRoleAuthorization);

        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
        config.EnableQuerySupport();
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));            

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( //MapHTTPRoute for controllers inheriting ApiController
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
            .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
            .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
        {
            ODataConfig.Register(config); 
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        });            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was, that I used LINQ and selected the loaded objects directly.
I had to use `select new` for it to work:

```
return Ok(from u in db.Users
          where u.UserId == key
          select new User
          {
              UserId = u.UserId,
              Name = u.Name
          });
```

This did **not** work:

```
return Ok(from u in db.Users
          where u.UserId == key
          select u);
```