# Odata: Blank page with no error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have these to models:

Magazine

```
public class Magazine
{
    [Key]
    publicint id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public virtual MagazineType Type { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MagazineType
{
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        publicstring Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Magazine> Magazines { get; set; }
}
```

And I auto-generated odata controllers using VS

```
<EntityType Name="MagazineType">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="Magazines" Type="Collection(PMDB.Models.Magazine)"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="Magazine">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Time" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="Type" Type="PMDB.Models.MagazineType"/>
</EntityType>
```

And this is my metadata. When I debug from the controller calling the Api it hits the function it's supposed to. I am sure that data comes from the DB. However, a blank page appears with no error or data.

Regards.

Update:

In the inspect element section it gives this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

Comment: It's better that you can share What's implemented in your controller?

Comment: its just return contex.Magazines; And I am sure that this returns the data.

Comment: Please include: HTTP level communication (URL, headers, body) for request & response.

Comment: forgive my noobness, can you explain it further?

Comment: So, it's strange. So, what's your request? What's the function hit?

Comment: I have fixed this issue with the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676879/webapi-and-odatacontroller-return-406-not-available by JeeShen Lee.