# Catch all exception in ASP.NET MVC + Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I know there are plenty of threads about this topic but none provides an entire and full working solution.

### Scenario

I have an application which is providing both, MVC 5 and Web Api 2.2 controllers.
I have the need of catching all exceptions (including 404, 401) and return always a custom JSON error structure.

### Partial Solution

So far I have implemented, a custom `ExceptionFilterAttribute` as following:

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            new
            {
                Title = "An Error occured while processing the request",
                Message = context.Exception.ToString(),
                Type = "Error",
                Code = context.Exception.HResult
            });
        context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "An Error occurred while processing the request";
    }
}
```

Then I also extended and replaced the available ExceptionHandler service as following:

```
public class GenericExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = HttpResponseFactory.BadResponse(
            context.Request,
            "An unhandled error occurred",
            context.Exception.Message,
            10000);
    }   
}
```

And I swap both during my initialization:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // authentication
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    // error handler
    config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
    // error service
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GenericExceptionHandler());
}
```

Unfortunately when I generate:

1. 401 - Not Authorized
2. 404 - Not Found
3. certain 500 - Internal Server Error

I cannot catch the exception. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: *when I generate*... Where? How?

Comment: have you tried to implement the `IExceptionLogger` ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I just send an non-authenticated request, I get back 401 but I can't intercept the response generated by ASP.NET stack

Comment: But were did you send that? And a 404 is definitely not an exception if you return `NotFound` from your controller, etc.

Comment: @PatrickHofman but what is the point of "debating"?
I am publishing APIs that have a strict requirement regarding the JSON format returned. Using Node.js I can easily return 401, 404 and even 403 with a customized JSON. I need the same with Web Api. Question? Is it possible or it is not?

Comment: I am not debating. I am trying to get enough information to write up an answer, if that is what you'd like me to do... :)

Comment: The question is easy. When ASP.NET (both MVC and Web Api) intercept a call which is a 401 or 404, neither the Exception Filter, or the global Error Handler Service, which I have already implemented, can intercept the call to modify the response. Is this possible for 401 and 404?

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that question when the OP is not even using global.asax?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `Global` file:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    // Do something with the error.
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception);

    // Redirect somewhere or return an error code in case of web api
    Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
}
```

Anytime, an error occurs, ASP MVC will call that method.

Comment: I am using OWIN, I don't have Global.asax

Comment: So add one. I do not think using OWIN means no Global.asax file.

Comment: For some reason this only catches some errors... e.g. if I navigate to a non-existent page, then `Application_Error` fires, but if an exception is thrown from the code then it doesn't..