# insert odata.mediaReadLink in the Odata response entity

Tags: odata

We have a media entity and we want to insert odata.mediaReadLink tag in the response.
"@odata.mediaReadLink": "urlroot/entityid/$value",

What is the best way to do it. We are using version 7.0 of Odata libs

Comment: see source files that do this in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851615)

Comment: I have this working in netcoreapp2.0 also if anyone needs help with it

Comment: @user326608 Can you post the solution for aspnet core?

Comment: @Norcino https://github.com/kevin-osborne/ODataSample